Would modern nuclear warheads with tritium issues still produce an explosion of a smaller yield?
I want to know how tritium functions in today's nuclear weapons. I would specifically or theoretically like to know how these warheads' efficacy will be affected by the absence of tritium. If they did not include tritium, would they still create a nuclear explosion of a smaller yield?
Most importantly, how would the effectiveness of a nuclear weapon be affected if tritium's shelf life was past due significantly? What impact would this have on the weapon's overall performance?
Would a 100-kiloton warhead fizzle out to be a 10-kiloton explosion, or would it not work at all?

If the fusion components fail, would the fission still cause a substantial explosion?

In nuclear weapons that depend on tritium, the tritium provides a burst of neutrons that ignites the fission chain reaction in the first stage.

@SolomonSlow Couldn't nuclear weapons use alternatives to tritium? Perhaps warhead designs can fall back to basic fission component like in WW2 style warheads???

This might help - Going Nuclear - The Science Of Nuclear Weapons

@TheT, Not sure what you mean by "basic fission component." Every nuclear weapon ever made except for the "Little Boy" and the Russian "Sloika" has used an implosion-type first stage. There's about a one microsecond time window during the implosion when a burst of neutrons will ignite the chain reaction. That's too short a time to rely on spontaneous fission, there must be some other neutron source. Several different designs have been used, and some (but not all) use tritium. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulated_neutron_initiator.
